# Who is marvin in com.stackexchange.marvin?

Tags: discussion, android-app

I just noticed that the package name of the Stack Exchange app is `com.stackexchange.marvin`.

[image]

Who is marvin? Is he the lone developer working on the Stack Exchange app?

Comment: The lone(ly?) developer is [Kasra](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/229741/kasra-rahjerdi)! Looks like he was hired specially to write the app but not sure he's the sole developer working on that. Based on answers and comments from devs, many of them are involved.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The main developers on the app are Kasra, Geoff, and myself, with some additional work by Kevin.

Comment: Cheers @balpha this makes a great team! :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is [Marvin, the Paranoid Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_the_Paranoid_Android). I.e., a geeky joke. It is, after all, an *Android* app?

[image: Marvin]

This compels me to quote my favorite Marvin lines:

> Now the world has gone to bed
>   Darkness won't engulf my head
>   I can see by infra-red
>   How I hate the night
>
> Now I lay me down to sleep
>   Try to count electric sheep
>   Sweet dream wishes you can keep
>   How I hate the night

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Comment: I get that it rhymes but he wasn't even paranoid! He was depressed but never especially anxious.

Comment: It was Zaphod that named Marvin a Paranoid Android; it only stuck because it rhymes, but that is not his official name.

Comment: What about [Marvin the Martian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_the_Martian) ?

Comment: @user137487: Because Marvin the Martian is no android. And besides, balpha (a Stack Exchange developer) has already confirmed my answer is correct.

Comment: Oh, well.  Still, I think the other Marvin would have made an ideal  Stack Overflow user. Pu238 modulator has gone missing, still has to look at that ugly Earth, blocking his view of Venus, what to do?

Comment: @Martijn "**a** developer??? He's **THE** developer! :P

Comment: The dew has clearly fallen with a particularly sickening thud this morning.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: *My capacity for mental activity of all kinds is as boundless as the infinite reaches of space itself. Except of course for my capacity for happiness.* -- *My capacity for happiness, you could fit into a matchbox without taking out the matches first.*

Comment: @MartijnPieters we could do this all day, but I'm going to refrain. Also, goosnargh.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: Well said.

Answer (score 10):

Surely he is [Marvin the Paranoid Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_the_Paranoid_Android).

[image: Marvin the Paranoid Android]

Brain the size of a planet, and I'm stuck writing a smartphone application on a primitive planet…