# What is zaphod?

Tags: discussion, android-app

In the `<head>` of every question page there is a meta tag such as this:

```
<meta name="twitter:app:url:iphone" content="se-zaphod://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246034/is-the-loading-icon-copyrighted-by-stack-exchange" />
```

[Marvin was explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192579/202832) for another app-related meta tag:

```
<meta name="twitter:app:id:googleplay" content="com.stackexchange.marvin">
```

...but what (or *who*) is zaphod?

Comment: Zaphod's just this guy, you know? (sorry, Hitchhiker's Guide reference :P)

Comment: @Doorknob: [Spoken](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wAuDhoRmzg&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFJREVL6RmMnZP5U7sGYYi2&t=5m24s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is most likely referring to [Zaphod Beeblebrox](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Zaphod_Beeblebrox), former President of the Galaxy:

> **Zaphod Beeblebrox**, or the **Big Z**, was a former President of the Galaxy. He was born on the fifth planet of Betelgeuse and was a semi-cousin of Ford Prefect, with whom he shared three of the same mothers. Due to an accident with a contraceptive and a time machine, his direct ancestors from his father were also his direct descendants.

Being kind of the boss of Marvin the android, it makes sense that's the name associated with Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

Not what, who - Its a reference to [Zaphod Beeblebrox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zaphod_Beeblebrox), so I guess someone is *really* a fan of h2g2. I wonder if this has anything to do with the fact that he has two heads

[image]